# How much more efficient are power-of-two textures?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping, texturing

I am creating an OpenGL video player using Ffmpeg and all my videos aren't power of 2 (as they are normal video resolutions). It runs at fine fps with my nvidia card but I've found that it won't run on older ATI cards because they don't support non-power-of-two textures.

I will only be using this on an Nvidia card so I don't really care about the ATI problem too much but I was wondering how much of a performance boost I'd get if the textuers were power-of-2? Is it worth padding them out?

Also, if it is worth it, how do I go about padding them out to the nearest larger power-of-two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a video player you should update your texture content using [`glTexSubImage2D()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml). This function allows you to supply arbitarily sized images, that will be placed somewhere in the target texture. So you can initialize the texture first with a call of [`glTexImage()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) with the data pointer being NULL, then fill in the data.

The performance gain of pure power of 2 textures strongly depends on the hardware used, but in extreme cases it may be up to 300%.

Comment: Okay, I am already using glTexSubImage2D() like you say but when I init the texture with glTexImage2D() should I create it as a power of two and then sort out the glTexCoord2f() calls to only show the video "part" of the texture for maximum efficiency?

Comment: It largely depends on your OpenGL implementation (read GPU). All the recent GPUs have a only very small performance hit for NPO2

Comment: Efficiency does not have to do do with rendering performance, but memory usage. So if I do not use power of two textures, will the driver round it up to nearest power of two, thus wasting memory?

Comment: @user877329: No, it won't upscale. Yes, you're right that these days memory bandwidth is the major concern. However when the pow2 constraint was set (early 1990-ies), the circuitry/codepaths to support mipmapping and downscaling from arbitrary resolutions were prohibitively expensive. However if you compare the corner case of (2\*\*x) vs. (2\*\*x)-1 the slowdown still is noticeable, albeit 8 years later nowhere near as bad as a decade ago.

Comment: @datenwolf Another choice than upscaling (which is a bad idea, being computational intensive) is zero-padding and modifying recalculating UV-coordinates.

Comment: @user877329: Doesn't work for wrap repeating texture application though (even if you jump over the gap by adjusting the texture coordinates in the shader, there'll still be a filtering discontinuity).