# OpenGL power of two texture performance

Tags: optimization, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much more efficient are power-of-two textures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245191/how-much-more-efficient-are-power-of-two-textures)

Old video cards support only power of two textures in OpenGL. In new hardware where non-power of two texures are supported, using power of two textures will be faster than NPOT?

Comment: "Old video cards do not support power of two textures in OpenGL." I think you mixed that one up. Older GPUs support **only** power of two textures.

Comment: Answers may vary with vendor, model (architecture), and in a few months, "new hardware" will mean something completely different.

Comment: OpenGL drivers work in mysterious ways. For example on the iPhone all integer coordinates are converted to floating point coordinates, making floating point coordinates marginally faster. Something like this could be going on where power-2 coordinates are processed in the same way as non-power-2 coordinates. Without extensive tests on specific platforms, the world may never known.